Manhwa where the female lead is a regressor with hidden healing powers
I don't fully remember the plot, but I remember a certain scene. Basically, the female lead is a regressor and has hidden healing powers. I also think she is a princess and is currently engaged to a blond male lead. Her brother brings foreign dignitaries to meet the king, but it was secretly a plot to assassinate him, since there were hidden bombs. The princess saves everyone, but the bombs still went off and revealed secret tunnels and caves below the throne room and she gets trapped there with the black-haired duke. She was originally going to leave him, but changes her mind and saves him. He sort of becomes the second male lead after this.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Any idea where this scene takes place in the story? The first few chapters? 40 chapters in? 100?

The Palace Beast - Main character is a princess with hidden healing powers, has a brother. But no mention of regression or a fiance, and she reveals her powers in like the 4th chapter. I don't think this is it despite the initial similarity.

"Do Not Hold on to the Broken Branch" - blonde fiance; protag is merely the daughter of a duke. The tags say she has hidden healing powers, but I didn't see any evidence of them while skimming.
